# Computer powers on, while monitor powers on and off

Tags: windows-7

We have been having this problem with our computer where it won't turn off and you have to hold down the power button to turn it off. My parents turned it off that way, while I was away for a weekend, and when I came back to turn it on, nothing happened.

The monitor has a green light that flashes on then off, but absolutely nothing appears on the screen. This has happened in the past, but when it did happen, you could always hear the start up sounds for Windows.

When it turned on this time, there was no sound.

Comment: Sounds like you suffered hardware failure.

Comment: Unplug your PC from the wall (leave the monitor plugged in, that's fine), take the side off your PC and locate the BIOS/CMOS battery, remove the battery for a couple of minutes, re-install the battery, put the cover back on the PC case, plug your PC back in to the mains, turn on and see if you have life.

Comment: @ciela16 Can you determine if it's the monitor or the tower that is malfunctioning?

Answer (score 0):

> **It had all of my translating pages in it.**

It seems you don't have any [backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup) copies of your important data.

I would open up the computer, remove the hard disk (which is nowadays likely to use a SATA connection), buy a SATA USB adapter, use that to connect the disk to another PC or notebook and make a backup copy of your translating pages.

Ideally, if the data is important, you should always make sure to have multiple copies at more than one location (i.e. not all in the same building).

Then you can proceed to fix or replace your computer without worrying about losing any important material.

Then make sure you always make backup copies of any new or changed data at least the same day you create or change it. Many people have their computers do this for them every day. You can use a local USB-attached disk and backup to some secure remote "cloud" storage service (or several, they occasionally go bust and lose your data).

> **when I came back to turn it on, nothing happened.**

See [Investigating cause of dead computer](https://superuser.com/q/191722/52492) and [How to test a power supply?](https://superuser.com/q/23788/52492)